# SQL to match the content of a nested XML node

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a database field containing XML nested like this:

```
<configuration>
   <modules>
    <genericMailer>
      <moduleContent>
        <data>
          <sendMethod>Email</sendMethod>
```

My XML can contain many instances of the `<genericMailer>` element (and it's subnodes). I want to find all rows where there are any instances of `<genericMailer>` where the `<sendMethod>` contains 'Mail'.

I can get all of the values for `sendMethod` like this:

```
SELECT  a.ApplicationId,
        x.XmlCol.value('(moduleContent/data/sendMethod)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS SendMethod
FROM    Applications a
CROSS APPLY a.AppConfig.nodes('/configuration/modules/genericMailer') x(XmlCol);
```

however I don't know how to search only for matching values. What's the WHERE clause I need?

Comment: What kind of database and what version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some possible ways :

a. Using `value()` method to extract `sendMethod` value then check if the value `LIKE '%mail%'` in WHERE clause :

```
SELECT  a.ApplicationId,
        x.XmlCol.value('(moduleContent/data/sendMethod)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS SendMethod
FROM    Applications a
CROSS APPLY a.AppConfig.nodes('/configuration/modules/genericMailer') x(XmlCol)
WHERE  x.XmlCol.value('(moduleContent/data/sendMethod)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') LIKE '%mail%'
```

b. Using XPath method `contains()` to check if `sendMethod` value contains substring `"mail"` and SQL Server method `exist()` to filter rows that pass the check :

```
SELECT  a.ApplicationId,
        x.XmlCol.value('(moduleContent/data/sendMethod)[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS SendMethod
FROM    Applications a
CROSS APPLY a.AppConfig.nodes('/configuration/modules/genericMailer') x(XmlCol)
WHERE x.XmlCol.exist('moduleContent/data/sendMethod[contains(.,"mail")]') = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, what's the [1] for against the node we're interested in?

Comment: @Izzy See the documentation of `exist()` : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx